# Draggable fusion Line Chart

Tags: draggable, fusioncharts

I found that fusion power charts provide the feature of dragging points on the chart. So do the fusion charts XT also have the similar feature?

Here is an example with Highcharts:
http://jsfiddle.net/highcharts/AyUbx/#

Or is there any alternative charts library with such feature?

Thanks,
-Chun

Answer (score 0):

FusionCharts XT is a collection of *regular* charts. The draggable charts that you highlighted here is a niche chart, and it is available only in the PowerCharts package.

You could either get the PowerCharts package separately, or go for the complete FusionCharts Suite, which includes FusionCharts XT + FusionWidgets XT + FusionMaps + PowerCharts.

Comment: I am thinking of that whether I can add such feature to FusionCharts. Is that possible?

Comment: @Kyleinincubator Nope, I don't think that's possible. The feature you want would be in PowerCharts only..